# on tap list view item flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello guy I'm new on flutter and I need help I have the next code but I would like to get the data from de item that I click I need to get the featureString: variable of the card, for that I'm using return InkWell ( onTap: () { but I cannot access to the data. if any one can help me!

thank you in advance!

here is my code:

```
class Features extends StatelessWidget {



  List<_FeaturePhoto> _feature() {
    return [
      _FeaturePhoto(imageURL: '',
          subtitle: 'I love cat',
          featureString: 'Cat'),
      _FeaturePhoto(imageURL: '',
          featureString: 'bird'),
      _FeaturePhoto(imageURL: '',
          title: 'Rabit',
          featureString: 'rabit'),
    ];
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    **return InkWell (
        **onTap: () {
         Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()));
          //here I need to get the data from the card item that I clicked
        },****
    child: Container(
        height: 320,
        width: 220,

        child: ListView(

            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            children: _feature().map<Widget> ( (photo) {
              return _FeatureGridItem(featurePhoto: photo);
              //Feature(photo);
            }).toList()
        )
    ));

  }
}

class _FeaturePhoto{
  _FeaturePhoto({
    this.imageURL,
    this.title,
    this.subtitle,
    this.featureString
  });
  final String imageURL;
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;
  final String featureString;
}


class _FeatureGridItem extends StatelessWidget {
  _FeatureGridItem({
    Key key,
    @required this.featurePhoto
  }) : super ( key: key);

  final _FeaturePhoto featurePhoto;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget> [

          Card(
            semanticContainer: true,
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[

                Image.network(featurePhoto.imageURL,
                    width: 230,
                    height: 230,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
                Positioned(
                    top: 175,
                    left: 10,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 25,
                      width: 100,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text( featurePhoto.featureString,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                )
              ],
            ),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
            ),
            elevation: 5,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),

          ),
        ]
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: You can use `onTap` event of ListView itself. Why do you need a separate Inkwell ?

Comment: thank you for you answer can you tell me how can I do it, I'm new on it I have only 1 week learning it!

Answer (score 0):

Listview has onTap event which will give you precisely what you need. Sample code below :

```
// Just a list of array to show in the list view
List<String> items = [
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three',
    'Four',
    'Five',
    'Six',
    'Seven',
    'Eight',
    'Nine',
    'Ten'
  ];



// Shows a list view     
ListView(
    children: items
    .map((data) => ListTile(
        title: Text(data),
       onTap: ()=>{                // <--------This is what you are looking for
           getListViewItems(data)
       }
      ))
      .toList(),
 ),

getListViewItems(String item){
  print(item);
}
```

I've taken the above code snippet from [here](https://flutter-examples.com/get-selected-item-from-listview-in-flutter/). which has a complete code you might want to refer.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try it!